# iphone recognize different shapes with finger movement

Tags: iphone, ios4, uigesturerecognizer

I'm developing an application for iPhone, and I want to detect different shapes as my fingers move on iPhone surface. Can anybody help me, how can I detect the different geometric shapes via finger movement or gesture in iPhone sdk.

Comment: That would be a case for custom UIGestureRecognizer implementations. Read the references and possibly watch the WWDC2010 session video on gesture recognizing.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, but it's not an easy task. iPhone SDK provides [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, you may create a subclass that UIGestureRecognizer that recognizes a distinctive gesture or character (in your case).

But there is also another approaches. One of them described by Brit Gardner in [his blog](http://britg.com/2011/07/17/complex-gesture-recognition-understanding-the-score/). Underlying this approach is the N-Dollar Recognizer based on JavaScript. This guy had done a nice job and now you can use [MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS](https://github.com/britg/MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS) library for detecting symbols and shapes. Of course, this library is not perfect and it use specific way (like JSON) to recognize touches, but it's better than nothing.

Thanks, hope this help someone.

Comment: Thanks berylium, but I cannot find any way how to implement it. SO can you please suggest me about implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample custom UIGestureRecognizer built inside the iOS SDK documentation which [recognizes a checkmark gesture here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html), specifically in the section entitled "Creating Custom Gesture Recognizers" (couldn't find an easy way to directly link the section). Using this as a template, you should be able write a custom gesture recognizer to correctly recognize your gesture.

The part you will have to provide yourself is the code which defines for your device what exactly it means to make your particular shape of interest.

Incidentally, I'm also in the process of writing my own custom UIGestureRecognizer as an example of recognizing a continuous gesture as opposed to the checkmark's discrete gesture recognition as I would have appreciated an example of this previously.

[It is available on Github.](https://github.com/futureperfect/PressDrag)

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2009 Daniele Margutti created MCGestureRecognizer project also based upon http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/

If you can find this it will give you a big heads up but will likely need updating to ios5. It used to be available at http://www.malcom-mac.com but that site seems to be down.