# Recognizing characters/handwritten characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, handwriting

I,ve been looking out for character/handwriting recognition API or web services that aptly serves the purpose of recognizing handwritten data..basically from a drawn objects on a `UIView` subtypes.For this query ,i ve explored `tesseract`(which seems to need a proper input preferrably typed text) to give a matched output.Ideally i would want to have a service like [visionobjects](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/write.html?locale=default).Most of them are paid API's including the one pasted above.

Are there any API /webservices matching the scenario like [visionobjects](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/write.html?locale=default)

Comment: I have searched for a library that does that for weeks and found nothing. Actually even vision objects is not a solution as they do online recognition (as the text is being written) and not offline.

Comment: @Moxy:yeah..i ve been doing the same and ended up on the wrong side of the result.I m not using vision objects,but would like some thing similar to that in context of iOS..

Comment: Check http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ and https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

Comment: @ACB : ive checked tesseract but its good where the input provided to it is kind of bold typed text..basically it recognizes computer typed characters else it gives weird outputs(Non human readable) 6 out of 10 times

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8786161/194544), hope it can help you..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a FREE API that recognizes hand writing for iOS in objective-c, I used this completed project :

https://github.com/eelretep/HandwritingTextField

Basically just download the project. Click on handwriting view, and write in the grey square, it should recognize your handwriting. The bad side is that it requires internet connection. If you have anything that does not require internet connection, please share.